# Copy/Clone mongodb database along with its data

Tags: mongodb

I need to copy my Mongo database along with its data. I have tried

```
db.copyDatabase( "Old_db", "new_db", "localhost" )
```

But the problem is it only copies a blank db, not with the previous data.

Comment: Do you intend to copy database on the same instance?

Comment: Have you looked at `mongodump` (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongodump/) and `mongoexport` (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongoexport/)?

Comment: I have tried the following command and it copies an existing database to a new database on the same host fine (including all the collection data)

db.copyDatabase('olddb', 'newdb', 'localhost')

I am not sure why you would need to dump the data and import it into the new database.

If you are having no luck then perhaps try the clone command:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.cloneDatabase/

You could even drop down below the wrappers and issue the mongo copydb command:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/copydb/

Comment: What version of MongoDB are you using?

Comment: db.copyDatabase has been deprecated in latest stable version

Answer (score 64):

**Feb 2019**

since `db.copyDatabase()` was deprecated in v4.0, you should use `mongodump` and `mongorestore` instead:

```
mongodump 
    --host <source host:port> 
    --ssl 
    --username <username> 
    --password <password> 
    --authenticationDatabase admin 
    --db <sourceDbName> 
    --collection <collection-name>
```

`mongodump` command will export the whole database into a local folder named `dump/<sourceDbName>` by default, then use `mongorestore` command to import to your target database:

```
mongorestore 
    --host <target host:port> 
    --ssl 
    --username <username> 
    --password <password> 
    --authenticationDatabase admin 
    --db <targetDbName>
    --collection <collection-name>
    <dump folder/file>
```

Examples:

```sh
# backup the whole db (mydb-old):
mongodump -h Cluster0-shard-0/sample-shard-00-00-xyz.mongodb.net:27017 \
--ssl -u user1 -p 123123 --authenticationDatabase admin \
-d mydb-old

# backup only one collection (mydb-old.users):
mongodump -h Cluster0-shard-0/sample-shard-00-00-xyz.mongodb.net:27017 \
--ssl -u user1 -p 123123 --authenticationDatabase admin \
-d mydb-old -c users

# restore the whole db (mydb-old) to mydb-new:
mongorestore -h Cluster0-shard-0/sample-shard-00-00-xyz.mongodb.net:27017 \
--ssl -u user1 -p 123123 --authenticationDatabase admin \
-d mydb-new dump/mydb-old

# restore only one collection (mydb-old.users) to mydb-new.users:
mongorestore -h Cluster0-shard-0/sample-shard-00-00-xyz.mongodb.net:27017 \
--ssl -u user1 -p 123123 --authenticationDatabase admin \
-d mydb-new -c users dump/mydb-old/users.bson
```

Find out more:

- [mongodump](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump)
- [mongorestore](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongorestore)

Comment: as an example, if you dont need special authentication, you can do these two commands: `mongodump -d old_db_name -o <path>` and `mongorestore -d new_db_name <path>/old_db_name`

Comment: Simplest usecase: `mongodump --archive --db=olddb | mongorestore --archive  --nsFrom='olddb.*' --nsTo='newdb.*'`

Answer (score 55):

You can use copydb or clone, or their helpers `copyDatabase()` or `cloneDatabase()`, but there are some considerations:

http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.2/tutorial/copy-databases-between-instances/#considerations

Maybe you are triggering some of them.

I just tested

```
db.copyDatabase("test","testCopy","127.0.0.1")
```

and it worked perfectly.

**Let us know if you got success.**

Comment: `db.copyDatabase` is deprecated in v4.0

Answer (score 21):

### For MongoDB v4.2+:

Older `copyDatabase` and `cloneDatabase` are deprecated. You should use a combination of `mongodump` and `mongorestore` instead.

### Example:

**Source DB:** [ name = `olddb` (host = `localhost`, port = `27017`) ]

**Dest. DB:** [ name = `newdb`  (host = `localhost`, port = `27017`) ]

### Approach 1 - By using an archive file:

1- Run mongodump to dump the `olddb` database to an archive `mongodump-old-db`:

```
mongodump --archive="mongodump-old-db" --db=olddb --host=localhost --port=27017
```

2- Run mongorestore with `--nsFrom` and `--nsTo` to restore (with database name change) from the archive:

```
mongorestore --archive="mongodump-old-db" --nsFrom='olddb.*' --nsTo='newdb.*' --host=localhost --port=27017
```

---

### Approach 2 - By using standard output stream:

instead of using an archive file, you can mongodump the `olddb` database to the standard output stream and pipe into mongorestore.

Just run:

```
mongodump --archive --db=olddb --host=localhost --port=27017 | mongorestore --archive  --nsFrom='olddb.*' --nsTo='newdb.*' --host=localhost --port=27017
```

**Tip:** You may include additional options as necessary, such as the uri (**--uri**) or host (**--host**), port (**--port**), username (**--username**), password (**--password**) or [other options](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/program/mongodump/#mongodump-options).

Source: [Official MongoDB Docs regarding the subject](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongodump/#mongodump-example-copy-clone-database).

Answer (score 5):

If you need to authenticate:

```
db.copyDatabase('crm', 'crm_copy', 'localhost', 'admin', '123456')
```

Comment: copyDatabase is deprecated
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/4.0-compatibility/#deprecate-copydb-clone-cmds

Answer (score 2):

I just copied the data/db file from a co-worker and it worked perfectly. I imagine it's a good idea to shut down any connections/mongod before doing so.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to have a look at the daemon(s). It happened to me that I had to reinitialize it/them (in my case I had a replica set)

Answer (score -5):

use MongoChef is very easy to do, create the same database locally, then copy collection of the source, then past to local newly created db.