# How to handle databases when testing with supertest?

Tags: javascript, testing, supertest

I can't find a conclusive answer to this. I don't know if I should use the production DB and delete the test documents that were created when all tests are run, or if I should make a clone of the DB and use that for testing, to avoid any unwanted behavior.

For now, I've been using the production DB and what I do is put the tests in this order: POST, GET, PATCH, DELETE. This way the DELETE test gets rid of the document created during the previous test/s. This works fine generally, but I'm pretty sure it is not a good practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your feeling that this is not a good practice is right IMHO. Testing on a productive system / database should never be the way to go. Here are some examples, what could happen:

- The final `DELETE` may fail or not be executed because of earlier failures or just be forgotten. Eventually, your production database will contain some useless residuals. These might be overseen and/or hard to remove manually.
- If you alter the wrong data sets by mistake, you might mess up productive data.
- Your testing stresses the ressources (CPU / storage / network) of the productive system. (Though this is insignificant, as I assume.)
- The credentials for the productive database access will be part of the test configuration, which might impose a security risk.

Cloning the productive DB, as you suggested, is one valid possibility, if the data contained isn't too sensitive. That keeps you as close as possible to the "reality" without endangering the productive data. Depending on the size of your production database, this might also be unnecessary expense. As your tests will probably need very little data, it is reasonable to deploy a test database containing only the data needed for your tests.

If I got your question right, you're even creating the database contents yourself during your test (`POST` / `INSERT`), retrieving them (`GET` / `SELECT`), altering them (`PATCH` / `UPDATE`) and then deleting the afterwards (`DELETE` / `DELETE`). So even an empty database with just the bare tables could suffice.

One last point: Depending on your setup, you might also not need to have the test database on the same DBMS (PostgreSQL / MariaDB / Oracle / ...) the production database is using. For test usage, you could just spin up some lightweight, transient database system like e. g. H2 or SQLite.

Comment: Thanks! One of the doubts i had was about the DB configuration if i chose to use a new one just for tests. I mean, for example, the indexes. But i guess you don't need them unless you are testing for performance, in which case it's not too much work to set it up a second time in the testing DB.
Do you have a useful resource to clone a Mongo DB? Just in case i find it more useful than creating a new one.

Comment: I'm happy I could help. :) Considering MongoDB cloning, there's a good resource here on SO as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14846712/copy-clone-mongodb-database-along-with-its-data You could do it like this and - if you want - execute an `TRUNCATE` on every table afterwards in order to have an empty test database.